# excel 2016 VBA asterisk wildcard causing 1004 application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I am trying to figure out what suddenly changed in excel to make my code stop working specifically because of the asterisk wildcard.  I had this code as a front end to combine data files (both **.xls** and .**xlsx**) into a blank file that contained the code shown below.  This was working fine and used numerous times without a problem.  The file itself and the code were done on Excel 2016 a few weeks ago.

Now when it runs, I am receiving **"run time error 1004 application defined or object defined error"** and I have no clue why.  I tinkered with the text on every line and I am pretty sure it is "*.xl*" that is causing the error.

I replaced the "*.xl*" with an actual file name from a destination folder and it worked no problem.  Why would using asterisk suddenly cause this error?

Has anyone ran accross this before ?  I have searched high and low and could not find anyone reporting something exactly the same.  Here is what I have been using, and again, it was working fine for a couple weeks now.

```
Sub MergeDataFiles()

Dim sPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim wBk As Workbook
sPath = InputBox("Paste File Path Here")
MyFile = Dir(sPath & "\*.xl*")

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & MyFile)
wBk.Sheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
wBk.Close True
MyFile = Dir()
Loop

ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: try `sPath & "\" & "*.xl*"`

Comment: use `Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\" & MyFile)`

Comment: Did you make sure your `sPath` doesn't already contain the backslash character?

Comment: Step through it with a debugger.  What is the value of `MyFile` when the error gets thrown?

Comment: Is the workbook you are in (i.e. the xlsm file) located in the same directory as the others?  If it is, your code will crash when it tries to open the already open file or, if it survives that, will definitely die when it gets to the next file and tries to copy a sheet after the (now closed) `ThisWorkbook`'s `Sheets(1)`.

Comment: @CallumDA    Moving the backslash did it.  Weird that it worked before then just stopped.

Answer (score 2):

I think the backslash ambiguity is causing the problem here.

I'd suggest removing it if it's there and then adding it in manually where the code requires it:

```
Sub MergeDataFiles()

Dim sPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim wBk As Workbook
sPath = InputBox("Paste File Path Here")

If Right(sPath, 1) = "\" Then sPath = Left(sPath, Len(sPath) - 1) ' strip away last backslash if present

MyFile = Dir(sPath & "\*.xl*")

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\" & MyFile) ' include backslash to keep full path correct
wBk.Sheets(1).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
wBk.Close True
MyFile = Dir()
Loop

ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```